# Is it possible to snap multiple photos from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I've been trying to find  something that is similar to this:[image]

I cannot seem to find anything on CocoPods or anything that will allow you to snap multiple photos and then return to a view with the snapped images. I can only find ones that will allow you to select them from the gallery multiple at a time, and return them. My question is: is it even possible to allow someone to snap multiple photos in one uipickercontroller as seen above?

Comment: You can use `cameraOverlayView` of `UIImagePickerController` to show camera preview and `- (void)takePicture` method to capture image(s). On taking each picture the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method calls so you can add each image to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **PhotoPicker** is a sample project provided by **Apple**, the sample project is downloaded at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196). It allows you to make own custom `OverlayViewController` . this sample project surely solve your issue.

the screen shot of the `xib` `overlay` name

[image]